# Obtener todos los "Lunes" en un rango de fechas

Tags: java, date

Necesito obtener una lista de fechas cuyos días sean "Lunes" en un intervalo de fechas suministrado, ambos inclusive.

**Por ejemplo:**

Si nos pasan el intervalo 01/05/2017 hasta 15/05/2017 la función debería devolver:

> 01/05/2017
>
> 08/05/2017
>
> 15/05/2017

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                                    
                                    
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
                                                                        
Calendar cini = Calendar.getInstance();
cini.setTime(formatter.parse(peticion.getDiaInicio()));
Calendar cfin = Calendar.getInstance();
cfin.setTime(formatter.parse(peticion.getDiaFin()));
                                    
while (cfin.after(cini)) {
    if (cini.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) {
        logger.info("---------->" + cini.getTime().toString() + " es Lunes ");
        dates.add(formatter.format(cini.getTime()));
    }
    cini.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
for(String c : dates){
    System.out.println("Fecha: " + c);
}
```

Con este código sólo me está devolviendo los dos primeros valores:

> 01/05/2017
>
> 08/05/2017

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Mmmm.... ¿hay alguna semana que no tenga 7 días, o que tenga más de un lunes? Igual no hace falta hacer la comprobación día a día...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es la condición del `while`.
Cuando llega a la tercera iteración, `cini=15/05/2017`, `cini` y `cfin` son iguales, con lo que no se cumple `cfin.after(cini)`.

Una posible solución sería cambiar la condición a

```
while (!cfin.before(cini)) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciona a la perfección

Answer (score 5):

En tu condición while debes agregarle una pregunta más, si cfin es igual a cini:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");    
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        Calendar cini = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            cini.setTime(formatter.parse("1/05/2017"));

            Calendar cfin = Calendar.getInstance();
            cfin.setTime(formatter.parse("15/05/2017"));
            while (cfin.after(cini) || cfin.equals(cini)) {
                if (cini.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) {
                    logger.info("---------->" + cini.getTime().toString() + " es Lunes ");
                    dates.add(formatter.format(cini.getTime()));
                }
                cini.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }
            for(String c : dates){
                System.out.println("Fecha: " + c);
            }
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Así te aseguras que compare la última fecha dada

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciona correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que nadie ha recogido el guante...

```
int diaInicial = cini.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int diferenciaDias = Calendar.MONDAY - diaInicial; // dias que faltan para el primer lunes.
if (diferenciaDias < 0) {
   diferenciaDias += 6;
}
cini.add(Calendar.DATE, diferenciaDias); // cini está en el primer lunes
while (!cfin.before(cini)) {
   dates.add(formatter.format(cini.getTime());
   cini.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); // Siguiente lunes
}
```

Un poco más generalizado aquí: https://ideone.com/v2yTVj

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aproximación, me gusta la idea, pero la acabo de probar y tengo el mismo problema, el último día no me lo devuelve

Comment: Cierto, entretenido con la parte de generar los lunes se me ha pasado arreglar el problema original (la comprobación en el `while`). He actualizado el código y el ejemplo.